# Open program on the 2nd monitor

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

I used `SetWindowPos` to move a window into the 2nd monitor.

Here are my steps:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(file.FullName);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);

Rectangle screen = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;
SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero,
                screen.Left, screen.Top, screen.Width, screen.Height, 0);
```

(file is a PlanarView (.pvs) app)

It has been moved into the 2nd monitor successfully. But after minimized and maximized, the window turn back the primary monitor.

Comment: do you have the code of the app? can you modify it?

Comment: No, i don't. I can't modify it

Comment: You could try SetWindowPlacement().  No guarantees of course, this is ultimately up to the program itself.

Comment: Can you wrap call to SetWindowPos in infinite loop with some small sleep, like 500ms?

Comment: @Hans Passant: Would you please give me some demo code?